# Simple representations of $L=C$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

What are the simple representations of the one dimensional Lie algebra $L=C$? This is for study so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All simple representations of finite-dimensional *solvable* complex Lie algebras are $1$-dimensional because of Lie's Theorem. Clearly, the $1$-dimensional Lie algebra is solvable, compare with

[Is the one-dimensional Lie algebra L=C semisimple?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3465587/is-the-one-dimensional-lie-algebra-l-c-semisimple).

Comment: I can understand how it is solvable since it is abelian and thus falls under Lies theorem. What would be an example of a simple representation then of it? @Dietrich

Comment: The trivial $1$-dimensional representation.